# Runtime permission: Android (called twice if user deny permission)

Tags: android, android-permissions, permission-denied

I have an issue with runtime permission alert dialog. This is my code:

```
button.setOnClickListener{
    requestPermissionLauncher.launch(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
}

val requestPermissionLauncher =
        registerForActivityResult(
            ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()
        ) { isGranted: Boolean ->
            if (isGranted) {
                presenter.openCamera()
            } else {
                showMessage(getString(R.string.permission_needed))
            }
        }
```

If user click on "Camera" btn, the user see this dialog (as expected):
[image]

Then, if the user clicks on "While using the app" or "Only this time" -> all OK, there is no issue

But if the user clicks on "Don't allow" -> he sees an error message (as expected), but if the user clicks on "Camera" btn at second time -> permission alert dialog appears one more time. (and after second time this dialog never appears again)

Why does this alert dialog apper twice if the user deny permission at first time? It should be appear only once, and after second click user might see an error message right away

Answer (score 17):

In short: Dialog appears twice because if the user clicks "Deny" at first time, next time system recommends to show a rationale dialog before asking for a permission, and shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) returns true. You can check if this is true and simply don't show your permission dialog again. If you don't check manually this boolean, and if it's true, system will automatically show permission dialog once again.
KEEP IN MIND THAT IF USER CLICKS OUTSIDE OF THE PERMISSION DIALOG, IT'S TREATED THE SAME AS IF A USER CLICKED ON "DENY".

When a user denies permission for the second time, you're not allowed to show permission dialog again. The only way for user to allow permission is to go to the app info in system settings and manually allow a requested permission (THIS IS NOT RECOMMENDED).

From [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting)

Workflow for requesting permissions =>

...

Step 4. Check whether the user has already granted the runtime permission. If not, continue to the next step.

Step 5. Check whether your app should show a rationale to the user, explaining why your app needs the user to grant a permission.

...

[Permission Graph from developer.android.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TC83m.png)

Example:

```
if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // Application can use camera
    } else if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
        /*
        This is the second time when system is about to show permission dialog.

        You can show your alert dialog here if you want to explain to user what are benefits if allow your requested permission (CAMERA in this case). Also, you can show
        permission dialog on "OK" click, and do nothing on "No, thank you".

        KEEP IN MIND THAT WITH THIS APPROACH YOU WILL SHOW ALERT DIALOG TO THE USER EVERY TIME YOU CHECK IF PERMISSION IS NOT GRANTED BUT
        shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) RETURNS TRUE. THIS CAN BE ANNOYING TO THE USER AND YOU SHOULD
        AVOID THIS PART OF CODE. THIS IS JUST FOR TESTING PURPOSES.

        *** YOU SHOULD SHOW THIS ALERT DIALOG WHEN REGISTERING YOUR ACTIVITY FOR PERMISSION RESULT, IF PERMISSION IS NOT GRANTED!!!***
         */
        AlertDialog.Builder(this@YourActivity)
            .setMessage(
                "Your message"
            )
            .setPositiveButton(
                "OK"
            ) { _, _ ->
                // Show permission dialog
                requestPermissionLauncher.launch(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
            }
            .setNegativeButton(
                "No, thank you"
            ) { _, _ -> }
            .create().show()

        /*
        IF YOU DON'T WANT TO SHOW ALERT_DIALOG FROM ABOVE, HERE YOU CAN SIMPLY SHOW PERMISSION DIALOG
        
        requestPermissionLauncher.launch(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
         */
    } else {
        /*
        This part of code is active first time when you are going to request the permission, and last time (after second "Deny" by a user,
        or simply, when permission is not granted and shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) returns false
         */
        requestPermissionLauncher.launch(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
    }
```

As I mentioned at the beginning, you can navigate user to the app settings where permission can be allowed, but according to Google's documentation you should avoid that.
Message from documentation: "...respect the user's decision. Don't link to system settings in an effort to convince the user to change their decision."

Even if you want to navigate user you can do that with next block of code:

```
val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS)
val uri = Uri.fromParts("package", packageName, null)
intent.data = uri
startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: "When a user denies permission for the second time, you're not allowed to show permission dialog again." Is there a way to know that the user has already denied the permission twice?

Comment: @Eselfar You can add another check for that: 
`if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && !shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) { // Permission is fully denied by a user (Denied twice) }` . This is also true at first time, but if you write if statement well, it shouldn't even reach this line.  If you need this, you can add this check after `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale` check, and before `else statement`. 
Hope this helps. Sorry for late response.

Comment: Hi @Sasa, thanks for the response.
I'm not sure on how to do that part: `This is also true at first time, but if you write if statement well, it shouldn't even reach this line`. Can you please details a little bit more?

Comment: @Eselfar in kotlin - 
val request : ActivityResultLauncher<String[]> 
request.launch(*) -> shows the permission dialog
check for result- if user has denied then check if shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(){
}

Answer (score -1):

if (!getSharedPreferences(getPackageName(), MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("apppermi", false)) {
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Permissionpage.class));
finish();
} else {
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, mainpage.class));
}
}

```
    }, 3000);
```

in java

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).